# Pass any URL parameters (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to be able to pass any parameters to an URL in Wordpress and then have them used as parameters in an iframe being shown on that page.

The iframe is located on the page `www.blog.com/downloads`. I want to able to create the URL `www.blog.com/downloads/?asset_id=123456` for example. And then have the parameters added to the iframe URL automatically so it becomes:

`<iframe src="<?php echo rtrim(get_field('iframe_url'),"/"); ?><PARAMETERS HERE>"></iframe>`

The URL of the iframe would then become `https://www.iframeurl.com?asset_id=123456`.

Is it possible to let any parameters be passed through the URL like this and then used in the template or do they need to be specifically defined first?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way.

```
add_query_arg( array(
    'asset_id' => '123456',
    .......
), 'https://www.iframeurl.com' );
```

Pass the parameter in the following way.

```
<iframe src="<?php echo rtrim(get_field('iframe_url'),"/"); ?>?asset_id=<?php echo $_REQUEST['asset_id']?>"></iframe>
```

Comment: Yes, but the question is how to pass the parameters through the URL of the Wordpress page down to the iframe living on that page.

Comment: @tobiasg Expand the answer, add how you can pass the id to the iframe URL.